# CircleCI - install dependencies step taking too long

Tags: yaml, circleci

The **Install Dependencies** step of my CircleCi YAML file takes about 3 minutes to run and I receive various warning about Python 2.7 going out of life in 2021. Is there anything I can do to speed it up and remove these error messages?

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/myapp
    docker:
      - image: node:10.13.0-stretch
        env:
          - DISPLAY=:99
          - CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: |
            npm install -g @angular/cli
            npm install
            npm install -g firebase-tools
            apt-get -y -qq update
            apt-get -y -qq install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
            if [[ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
              apt-get -y -qq update
              apt-get -y -qq install python-dev
              curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
              python get-pip.py --user
              echo 'export PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
              source ~/.bash_profile
              pip install awscli --upgrade --user
              ~/.local/bin/aws configure set default.s3.signature_version s3v4
            fi
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run:
          name: Deploy to AWS
          command: |
            if [[ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
              ng build --prod --configuration=production --progress=false
              ~/.local/bin/aws --region eu-west-2 s3 sync /root/myapp/dist/myapp/ s3://$AWS_BUCKET_TARGET --delete --exclude '.git/*'
              ~/.local/bin/aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $AWS_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths '/*'
            fi
    branches:
      only:
        - master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your configuration, it looks like you're building an Angular application w/ Python and deploying to AWS.

Here are some recommendations:

- Instead of using a Node image and installing Python, have you considered using a [pre-made Python/Node image variant](https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/python)? These are images that already have both Python and Node installed. This should cut down time a lot.
- Also noticed you're installing Angular CLI and firebase-tools globally. Global npm modules are installed in a different folder than the current project's `node_modules`. If you want to cache those dependencies too, recommend just installing without `-g` flag, or additionally supplying the global modules folder to the `save_cache` and `restore_cache` steps so you don't have to reinstall those from scratch every time.
- If you're not using CircleCI's server product, you can use v2.1 config and make use of CircleCI's [AWS CLI orb](https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/aws-cli) to install the CLI as needed. Here's an example:

```yaml
version: 2.1 # 2.1 required for orbs
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@1.3.0

# ...

  steps:
    # ...other dependency installation steps as required

    - aws-cli/install # Call pre-made commands in orb
    - run:
        command: |
          aws configure set default.s3.signature_version s3v4

    # ...etc.
```

- This isn't totally related to the question, but I noticed you're using some deprecated configuration. You can remove your bash checks for `$CIRCLE_BRANCH` in all the steps as well as the final `branches` key. Instead, declare a [workflow with a filter](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#branch-level-job-execution) like so:

```yaml
workflows:
  build-deploy: # arbitrary workflow name of your choice
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```